# How to get latest date from SQL table

Tags: sql

So I have two tables:

1. `workersTbl (workerName and workerID)`
2. `workersLogTbl (workerID and workerLogTime)`

e.g. `workerTbl: workerName = John Smith | workerID = 5`

When you pull the workerLogTbl (i.e.

```
 SELECT * FROM workerLogTbl where workerID = 5
```

This should give you multiple times the worker logged in.

How do I pull all the workers names and also pull the latest log in time (supposing I join the two tables using `workerID`)?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try adding a `GROUP BY w.workerId` clause, and an aggregate in the SELECT list, `MAX(t.workerLogTime)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

`select l.*
from workerlogtbl l
inner join workerstbl w on l.workerid = w.workerid
where l.workerid = 5
order by l.workerlogtime desc`

what i have done is join the two tables together with the common fields from both tables and then ordered by the workerlogtime in descending order.  if you need more info on joins take a look [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

The first way is to use an inner join, which assumes every worker you are interested in has an entry in the workersLogTbl

```
SELECT w.workerName, max(wl.workerLogTime) as LastLogTime
    FROM workersTbl w
      INNER JOIN workersLogTbl tl on (w.workerId = wl.workerId)
    WHERE (w.workerId = 5)
    GROUP BY w.workerName
```

A second way uses an outer join.  This is useful to capture those workers who do not have an entry in the workersLogTbl.  Note that if there is no corresponding entry in workersLogTbl then LastLogTime will be null.

```
SELECT w.workerName, max(wl.workerLogTime) as LastLogTime
    FROM workersTbl w
      LEFT OUTER JOIN workersLogTbl tl on (w.workerId = wl.workerId)
    WHERE (w.workerId = 5)
    GROUP BY w.workerName
```

note that the `outer` word isn't generally necessary: `left join` is normally sufficient.

A third way is to use a subquery.  This is useful if you are also wanting to get other aggregate results in the same query.  Such as if we wanted the first and last log time for the worker, for example:

```
  SELECT w.workerName, 
     (SELECT MAX(wl.workerLogTime) FROM workersLogTbl wl WHERE wl.workerId = w.workerId) as LastLogTime,
     (SELECT MIN(wl.workerLogTime) FROM workersLogTbl wl WHERE wl.workerId = w.workerId) as FirstLogTime
    FROM workersTbl w
    WHERE (w.workerId = 5)
```

**side note:**
Don't name your tables with `Tbl` on the end.  It's obvious that is a table and doesn't need the suffix and is simply noise.  Also, use regular capitalization for the column names.  ie: `WorkerId` instead of `workerId`

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Try adding a `GROUP BY w.workerId` clause and adding aggregate function in the SELECT list, `MAX(t.workerLogTime)`. –

```
SELECT w.workerId
     , MAX(t.workerLogTime) AS latest_time
  FROM worker w
  LEFT
  JOIN workerLogTbl t 
    ON t.workerId = w.workerId
 GROUP BY w.workerId
 ORDER BY w.worderId
```

Comment: I re-read the question, and missed that you wanted to return the `workerName` column... you should be able to figure out how to modify the query in my answer to do that. NOTE: I used an outer join so that we would be to sure to return _all_ rows from workerTbl, even if there is no matching row in workerLogTbl. If you only want rows that have a matching for in workerLogTbl, remove the keyword `LEFT`.